# "Call" vs. "Call at"

Tags: prepositions

Consider

> I will call your office some time in the evening.

vs.

> I will call **at** your office some time in the evening.

Which is correct — the version with 'at', or the version with no preposition?

Answer (score 9):

They mean different things.

> I will call your office ...

means you will use a telephone.

> I will call at your office ...

means you will show up in person.

Comment: I've never heard of "call at" there enters a new phrase in my vocabulary!

Comment: A related phrase is "to come calling".

Comment: _Call (at)_ meaning _visit in person_ is a bit dated, but used to be common in the UK. There was a time when a remark like _I will call tomorrow_ was actually ambiguous - some people had adopted the meaning of _phone_ from across the Atlantic, while others still used it to mean _come in person_.